# Creating (my own) TypeScript Library

Tags: javascript, typescript

Following the tutorial on [this page](http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/creating-your-own-javascript-library/)
I have the following JavaScript:

```
function A(id) {
    var about = {
        Version: "0.0.0.1",
    };

    if (id) {
        if (window === this) {
            return new A(id);//<-Error in typescript
        }

        this.e = document.getElementById(id);
        return this;
    } else {
        return about;
    }
};

A.prototype = {
    doSomething: function () {
        //Some logic
        return this;
    }
}
```

JavaScript Usage:

```
var result = A("test");//The type of result should be 'A'
result = new A("test");//The type of result should be 'A'
result = A("test").doSomething();//The type of result should be 'A'
result = new A("test").doSomething();//The type of result should be 'A'
```

I want to create a library based on TypeScript that has the same usage. How can that be done?

If I try to just put this in a '.ts' file and compile I get an error saying: Error TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.

Also I am not sure how the usage with and without the 'new' keyword can be achieved as I am trying to make a library in typescript that can be used in javascript and not to make the user have to use the 'new' keyword.

**P.S.**
I know I can create a javascript file with a '.d.ts' file but that is not the purpose.

Comment: The one who down voted can at least explain why?

Comment: what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: still not clear. what's up with using `new`? what are you trying to achieve? also, what's `doSomething`? as it's not in the code at all. It will be best if you explain exactly what you want, because I'm not about to read that tutorial you linked to

Comment: @NitzanTomer Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is trying to reconcile the multiple purposes of `A()` and doesn't have enough information to figure out what you want it to look like.

[This works](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20A(id)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09if%20(window%20%3D%3D%3D%20this)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20A(id)%3B%2F%2F%3C-Error%20in%20typescript%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09this.e%20%3D%20document.getElementById(id)%3B%0D%0A%09return%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20result%20%3D%20A(%22test%22)%3B%0D%0Aresult%20%3D%20new%20A(%22test%22).doSomething()%3B%0D%0A):

```
function A(id): void {
    if (window === this) {
        return new A(id);//<-Error in typescript
    }

    this.e = document.getElementById(id);
    return this;
};

let result = A("test");
result = new A("test").doSomething();
```

But adding the version return block is confusing the compiler because `A` is now acting like two totally different things.

If you want to force the compiler to ignore the complaint you can do this:

```
function A(id): void {
    var about = {
        Version: "0.0.0.1",
    };

    if (id) {
        if (window === this) {
            return new A(id);//<-Error in typescript
        }

        this.e = document.getElementById(id);
        return this;
    } else {
        return <any>about;
    }
};

let result = A("test");
result = new A("test").doSomething();
```

But I don't recommend it. What you are trying to do is part of what TypeScript is trying to protect against. I don't know of a way to make the typings on this one "just work".

---

Edit: In response to your comment, I recommend something more like this:

```
class A {
    public static about = {
        Version: "0.0.0.1"
    };

    private e: HTMLElement;

    constructor(id) {
        this.e = document.getElementById(id);
    }

    public doSomething() {
        //Some logic
        return this;
    }
}

let result = new A("test");
result.doSomething();

let about = A.about;
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question to reflect better what I want. Also, can I do this using class or something else that is more suitable for typescript?

Comment: I updated my answer with a more detailed example. If you really need both `A(id)` and `new A(id)` patterns it gets more tricky. I chose to only keep the `new A(id)` pattern.

Comment: I need both. I want the JS users not to get an exception just because they didn't do 'new'. How is that possible? Can you show an example?

Comment: @RandallFlagg `class` in es6 is always run in strict mode, so it will throw an error without `new`. From my opinionated perspective: If you're making a brand new library, plan it around es6. Your consumers will have to learn it anyway. Don't hack the language just to let your consumers write incorrect code.

Comment: @MrHen Thanks for your help. That is basically what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I came up with thanks to MrHen help:

```
class A {
    public element;
    public test;
    public doSomething;

    constructor(id) {
        if (id) {
            if (window === this as any) {
                return new A(id);//<-Error in typescript
            }

            this.element = document.getElementById(id);
            this.test = function () {
                console.log("testing"); return this;
            };
            this.doSomething = function () {
                console.log("doing something"); return this;
            };

            return this;
        }
    }
}

let result = ((A as any)("test") as A).doSomething();
result = new A("test").doSomething();
```